# tooltip isn't displaying in css when textsize is large

Tags: html, css

```
  <a class="ctooltip" tooltip="Definition:1000 characters here 
  onclick="openDocumentTypeHistory(2110)" href="#" >mytestdocument</a>
```

the CSS style function

```
.ctooltip{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
    }
                  .ctooltip:hover:after{
        background: #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 2px;
            border-color: #000000;
            border-style: ridge;
            border-width: 1px;
            top: 26px;
            text-decoration: none;
        color: #1d3030; 
        left: 20%;
            content: attr(tooltip);
        padding: 5px 15px;
             position: absolute;
        z-index: 98;
            width: 220px;
           max-width: 220px;
    }
           a:hover {text-decoration: none; }
```

> when the text size is large I can't display the entire tooltip message(more than 1000 characters,how can i fix this?

Comment: can you put your code here

Comment: Share your script... there is no problems with basic tooltip implementation

Answer (score 0):

here is an example with a long tool-tip value:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas bibendum ac felis id commodo. Etiam mauris purus, fringilla id tempus in, mollis vel orci. Duis ultricies at erat eget iaculis.">Hover here please</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("a").tooltip({
    'selector': '',
    'placement': 'top',
    'container':'body'
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.tooltip-inner {
   max-width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: can you look at the code I provided post-edit and help me fix?